# Why aren't these two question equal?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

[image]

Firstly I doubt whether the 12 is right in Q1.If it is right,please give a proof.
Secondly why (1) is not equal to (2) in Q2?

Comment: (1) is valid for $0{\color{red}<}x<\pi$. If you did not make mistake, then there should be (1)=(2).

Comment: Don't you see -pi{\color{red}<}x<\pi?

Answer (score 2):

Of course (1) is not the same as (2).

The expression "$x = 2 ( \sin x / 1 - \sin 2x / 2\dots)$" really only holds for $x\in (-\pi,\pi)$. This is derived by taking the Fourier series. The more accurate statement is

$$ S(x) \approx 2 (\frac{\sin x}{1} - \frac{\sin 2x}{2} + \cdots) \tag{a}$$

where $S(x)$ is the [Sawtooth function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) that equals $x$ in $(-\pi,\pi)$ and extended $2\pi$-periodically (roughly speaking, it is the value of $x$ "mod $2\pi$"). Expression (a) is valid for all $x$ that is not odd integer multiples of $\pi$ (where the function $S(x)$ is discontinuous).

When you do the change of variables $x = \pi - y$ to obtain your expression (1), you have

$$ S(\pi - y) \approx 2( \frac{\sin y}{1} + \frac{\sin 2y}{2} + \cdots) $$

using the properties of the trigonometric functions, but $S(\pi - y)$ is only equal to $\pi - y$ for $y \in (0,2\pi)$, and **not** $y\in (-\pi,\pi)$.

In particular, $S(\pi - y)$ has a discontinuous jump at 0 (and all even multiples of $\pi$). This is what the function you described using (1) represents.

The function you described using (2) is a different sawtooth function. This one is equal to $(\pi - y)$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$ and repeats with period $2\pi$, having discontinuities at all odd multiples of $\pi$. Or, we can write it as $\pi - S(y)$.

Clearly $\pi - S(y) \neq S(\pi - y)$.

---

The moral of the story is that "*when an expression is only valid on some domain, a derivation assuming that the expression holds outside of that domain will likely lead to falsehoods*". (Or, the well-known logic fact that a false hypothesis can imply any conclusion.)

---

To answer Q1 it is simplest to directly compute the Fourier series for the $2\pi$-periodic function that equals $x(\pi - x)(\pi + x) = x\pi^2 - x^3$ on the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$.

We have that the function is clearly odd, so the $\cos$ coefficients vanish.

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^3 \sin(nx) \mathrm{d}x = (-1)^{n+1}  \frac2n \pi^3 + \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{3x^2}{n} \cos(nx) \mathrm{d}x = (-1)^{n+1} \frac2n \pi^3 - \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{6x}{n^2} \sin nx \mathrm{d}x $$

The first term cancels the contribution from $x\pi^2$. The second term gives you the factor of 12.

Comment: I like your word *falsefoods*...

Comment: @GEdgar: quite fitting, considering I've been suffering the past few days thanks to some questionable mayonnaise. Anyway, fixed. (And c'mon, you have 18K... couldn't you have fixed it for me? Next time pretty please?)